# laravel 8 join query table.column_name does not work in blade or controller

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

here is my code:

```
$data = Courses::select('courses.id','courses.standid', 'courses.publisher', 'courses.coverpic', 'courses.course_sts', 'standards.standtitle AS stitle', 'subjects.subtitle AS btitle')
                ->join('subjects', 'subjects.id', '=', 'courses.subjectid')
                ->join('standards', 'standards.id', '=', 'courses.standid')
                ->get();

and blade codes are:

@foreach ($data as $row)
<p>{{ $row->stitle }}</p> 
@endforeach
```

the query works fine when i check dd($data) under attributes, but the stitle and btitle columns never shows inside blade as {{ $row->stitle }} or {{ $row->btitle }}

what am I missing or how to collect the joining table column into the blade file?

cheers

Comment: Can you add the full controller method and the rendered HTML to your question? (wondering after inspecting element on the web does it show `<p></p>` for the right number of rows or is the `$data` variable not getting sent to the blade properly)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response. It was the redirect method that taking me back to history page rather then the post update status.

it was return redirect **(*the_view_name*)->with(*vars*)**

instead of return view **(*the_view_name*)->with(*vars*)**

my first experience to ask a question at stackoverflow and resolved by myself.